# Qt: Rotating a label with a Pixmap on it

Tags: qt, label, rotation, pixmap

I have a label with a pixmap on it
Code looks like this:

```
Label = new QLabel (dialog, Qt::Widget);
Label -> setGeometry( xPosition, yPosition, 25, 87 );
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load("/home/richter/Dokumente/QDevelop/AnimationTest/ScreenData/rightTire.png", 0, Qt::DiffuseAlphaDither);
Label -> setPixmap(pixmap);
Label -> setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
Label -> show();
```

what I now want to have is a method like that:

```
void rotateLabel (int degrees)
```

I think it's clear what it should do. You enter the degrees and see it rotated by these degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Run `qtdemo` -> Demonstrations -> Embedded Dialogs

It shows how to map a whole dialog to a 3D surface. The same technique allows you to rotate a single label.

Source code is here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/demos-embeddeddialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the examples in [QMatrix](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix.html).

You need to override paint event of your QLabel and draw similar to given example.